# Experimental Realization of Superactivation of Quantum Capacity

Tags: resource-request, quantum-operation, channel-capacity

The [*superactivation*](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/activation-bound-entanglement) of quantum capacity is an effect that some quantum channels present such that is two of those channels with zero capacity are combined, a non-zero channel capacity can be achieved for the combined channel. This is obviously an effect that can only happen in the quantum world, as it is known that in classical communications two zero-capacity channels give a zero-capacity channel when combined.

This is one of the most surprising and weird effects known from quantum information theory, and so I am wondering if someone can give reference about an experimental realization of such effect.

Answer (score 3):

The paper [Superactivation of Multipartite Unlockable Bound Entanglement](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.190501), presented the first experimental realization of the following superactivation: Alice and Charlie have zero entanglement. Bob and Charle have zero entanglement. But Alice, Bob, and Charlie have non-zero tripartite entanglement.

Six years earlier was the experimental demonstration of a slightly different type of superactivation was done in [Superactivation of Multipartite Unlockable Bound Entanglement](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.190501).

One year further back, there was [Generation and superactivation of bound entanglement](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5943448/), which was an experimental demonstration of superactivation in involving only bound entanglement.